# One bicep template for slot and no-slot azure functions deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'm wondering if it's possible to support both slot and no-slot azure functions deployment using one bicep template without if statements?

My main concern is setting function app configuration. When I want to configure a slot, I use a resource with type `Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config`, but when it comes to configuring "main" slot on a non-slot function app, `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` type is used. I want to be able to deploy my function app to various environments - some of them use slots, but some of them do not. It would be nice if I could use `Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config` resource to configure "main" slot on non-slot function app and additional slot on slot function app and use variable to select slot. Is it possible? Or the only way to do it is to use conditional deployment?

Background: I have separate azure environments for development, staging and production. Separate resource groups, separete function apps. On dev environments I don't want to use slot feature - to minimize deployment time. On the other hand, on the staging and production environment slots are must have. I don't want to maintain two separate templates. Using conditional deployment is also not satisfying. Ideal solution would be treating the only one slot in a non-slot environment just like a normal slot in a slot environment.

Comment: Why are you not wanting to use a conditional deployment? It would be the fastest way to accomplish what you're wanting.  You could probably use a module but it will take more time and add unneeded complexity.

Comment: Just a suggestion here, but does using slot format and passing "Production" work?

Comment: are you more concern about reusability: you don't wanna define the settings multiple times as they kind of looks like the same anyway ?